# A bug within the console with typeof?

Tags: javascript, object, null, typeof

I'm still sort of new to JavaScript and so I was playing around with some Javascript. I used `let car = null;` and had `console.log(car)` into the console which came up to null of course. I then `console.log(typeof car)` into the console this time but came back as an object. I was wondering why since I `let car = null`?

`let car = null; console.log(car); //came back as null  console.log(typeof car); //came back as object`
So I thought that would come back as null as well after I `console.log(typeof car);` but didn't and came back as an object.

Comment: It's worth nothing that `undefined` however, has its own type: `typeof undefined === "undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

It's the behavior of this operator - check [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

[image]

Comment: Pictures of code/text are as unappealing in an answer as they are in a question.

Answer (score -1):

w3schools states [the following](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_typeof.asp#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%20null%20is%20%22nothing,typeof%20null%20is%20an%20object.)

> In JavaScript null is "nothing". It is supposed to be something that
> doesn't exist.
>
> Unfortunately, in JavaScript, the data type of null is an object.
>
> You can consider it a bug in JavaScript that typeof null is an object.
> It should be null.